# AngularJS Post Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

AngularJS Post Call

I am getting 502 error when post raw payload id = "DMQvzbIo1471761028"
if I use id as "123456789012345678" it works fine.

This is strange. But I could not find what is going wrong.

```
    //id = "DMQvzbIo1471761028"
    id = "123456789012345678"

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/#/something/",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: {"id":id}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("I am success")
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("I am error")
    })
```

If I use any other rest client instead of angularjs, then post call works even with post data

```
    { "id":"DMQvzbIo1471761028" }
```

but same data is not working in angular. I could not find what is going wrong. Please let me know what is going wrong.

To my surprise in angularjs  if I change id as "**DMQvzbIo1471761028XXX**" it works again. 
And if I prune some character  "**DMQvzbIo147176102**" again it works 
but with value "**DMQvzbIo1471761028**" it not working. Please let me know what is going wrong.

### Server Side Code: Python Flask

```
    @app.route("something/", methods=['POST'])
    def hello():
        data = request.json
        print data
        return "Hello World!"
```

Comment: a 502 error is on your server, and it is impossible for anyone not familiar with your project to understand why the server would generate this error without knowing what this `id` you are trying to pass represents.

Comment: If it server side error then why it is working with other rest client for same value "DMQvzbIo147176102" . Even for angular js it works with value "DMQvzbIo1471761028XXX" and "DMQvzbIo147176102".

Comment: right, clearly doesn't make sense, but also doesn't change the fact that people not involved in your project or with a full copy of both your server and client code don't have enough information to troubleshoot the problem for you.

Comment: for example, if it were an issue with angular dropping the last character, then `1234567890123456789` wouldn't work, while `123456789012345678` would (based on the length of the supplied "non-functional" `id` value (presumably, depending on what the server is doing with these values).

Comment: @Claies Added server side code. I guess there is no problem with server side.

Comment: there is absolutely no evidence at all that a ***specific*** value being provided in the data payload of a server request would cause something unrelated (`HTTP 502 Bad Gateway`) to occur.

Comment: Is there a rogue closing parenthesis after the definition of the "data" property in the $http call's configuration object? Not sure if it's just a copy paste error, or actually affecting results.

Comment: sorry @austinbruch it is copy paste error